# I am trying to draw the line in the middle. I tried different coordinates

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

[image]Here is my paintComponent which contains the coordinates

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; 
        g2.drawLine(-100,0,500,0);
        g2.drawLine(141,-500,141,500);
        g2.translate(getWidth()/2.0, getHeight()/2.0);
        g2.scale(1,-1);
        g2.rotate(45*Math.PI/180);
        Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,100,100);
        g2.fill(r);
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: An explanation of what your expected results should be might also help

Comment: let me insert a image

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you please click the link it will take to the result: http://postimg.org/image/hxl2ovn19/

Comment: Now, I assume you want the rectangle to be aligned to the line?

Comment: yes i want the origin to be alligned

Comment: *"yes i want the origin to be alligned"* to what?

Comment: i uploaded the end result image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit of a cheat, but...

[image: Origin]

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
    g2.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight()/ 2);
    g2.translate(getWidth() / 2.0, (getHeight() / 2.0));
    g2.scale(1, -1);
    g2.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);
    Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Double(-50, -50, 100, 100);
    g2.fill(r);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

Basically, the origin point is now the center of the screen, so in order to draw the rectangle "centered" around the origin point, you need to adjust the x/y accordingly

Now, you also adjust the origin point by `50x50` instead, but then you'd need to change the anchor point around which the `Graphics` context is rotated to the center of the box

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
    g2.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight()/ 2);
    g2.translate((getWidth() / 2.0) - 50, (getHeight() / 2.0) - 50);
    g2.scale(1, -1);
    g2.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180, 50, 50);
    Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100);
    g2.fill(r);
    g2.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MadProgrammer